# How to combine results of several repositories into a single result set without creating too much coupling in Domain?

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

Imagine we have a four entities in the domain: `Product` that is produced, `Technology` that defines the product type, `Material` that is used during manufacturing process and `Category` to which the `Material` belongs. There are many `Categories` that can be nested within categories, the hierarchy depth has no limits. A `Product` can be made from various combinations of `Materials`.

Lets say we define `Technology` by adding or removing certain parent `Categories`. Then we create `Product` based on `Technology` and add/remove certain `Materials` that belong to `Technology's Categories'` subtrees.

If I wanted to render a list of top-level `Categories` with the `Materials` of the `Categories` subtrees belonging to a certain `Product`, my `ProductRepository` has to know the internal workings (e.g., nested tree implementation) of the `CategoryRepository` to be efficient. Otherwise I end up loading bunch of Collections and lose all the benefits of RDBMS.

What would be the correct way of reaching my goal in terms of Domain driven design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to place the method in CategoryRepository if you want some Category:

```
public interface CategoryRepository {
    List<Category> findWithMaterialsOfCategoriesSubtreesBeloningTo(ProductId productId);
}
```

And as far as I know, Knowing the structure of product is the only feasible and effcient way of implementing this.

Please allow me to quote Eric Evan's dddsample:

```
public interface HandlingEventRepository {


   /**
    * @param trackingId cargo tracking id
    * @return The handling history of this cargo
    */
    HandlingHistory lookupHandlingHistoryOfCargo(TrackingId trackingId);
}
```

What if the requirment changed to returning all HandlingEvent of an unshipped cargo? Then I have to join t_cargo and t_handling_event and filtering by "where t_cargo.status = ?".

Answer (score 1):

> If I wanted to **render** a list of top-level ...

"Rendering" is a presentation concern: it shouldn't affect the design of the domain model.

Thus, if you *just* need to **show** such kind of view, just use the best SQL query you can write.

As far as I can understand, the `Product` class provided by the repository should contain only the [identifiers](http://epic.tesio.it/doc/manual/shared_identifiers.html) of the `Materials` and the materials should contain only the [identifiers](http://epic.tesio.it/doc/manual/shared_identifiers.html) of the pertinent `Categories`. However this is true only if Products requires Categories to enforce their invariants!

However from your description of the requirements, I wouldn't adopt a DDD approach but a simpler CRUD one. As a rule of thumbs, you don't need DDD if you don't need to hire a domain expert to understand the business logic (and if you can reconduct all the business rules to RDBMS constraints).

Comment: I agree completely about the rendering part - that is no concern of the domain. Yet if there's a need to show such result, a need to interact with it might arise later. I thought I might be failing to see an important Entity or relationship here. My question is simplified, the actual domain is much more complex - we tried the CRUD approach and failed miserably. Anyways, thanks for the input.

Comment: I didn't questioned the relationship, but the way to model it: don't use in memory object references, just identifiers (that are cheap value objects). However, by your comment I would consider if you are handling a projection (thus the SQL suggestion still applies) over different bounded contexts. Consider if splitting the domain into different bounded contexts can reduce the cognitive load: perhaps you have a context for product managements and one for materials' taxonomies, for example.